# Spaces in the name is breaking the download?

Tags: php, file, header, download, pragma

Ok so i have this code that will allow a user to download a song

```
$file = DIR_DOWNLOAD . $download_info->row['filename'];
$mask = basename($download_info->row['mask']);
$mime = 'application/octet-stream';
$encoding = 'binary';

if (!headers_sent()) {
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: ' . $encoding);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)));
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    $file = readfile($file, 'rb');
```

The problem is that if the song has a space in it like `sinsita happy 1  SONIFI.mp3` the user will only download a text file named `sinsita` ...any ideas how to fix this behavior

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to quote the file name in the content disposition:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)) . '"');
```

Edit: Now that also means that if the file name contains a quote; then you have to escape that quote. So really your code looks like this now:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . str_replace('"', '\\"', ($mask ? $mask : basename($file))) . '"');
```

Comment: this worked great but in chrome its not even downloading...but in safari and firefox its working perfect...any ideas

Comment: @Tamer: I don't think that is related to this issue. What happens if you remove the `filename` all together? (Smoke testing to see if that is the issue)

Comment: Small note: I used double quote in the header with single quotes wrapping the filename, that didn't work. Quote usage should be as the answer above.